# Why did it rain after they jumped on a cloud?

Tags: plot-explanation, puss-in-boots

During a scene in [Puss in Boots](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0448694/) (2011), Puss and Kitty jump onto a cloud where Humpty jumped a moment earlier, and some rain falls from the cloud. Why does that happen? Is it to make it more "realistic"? Or is it a joke that I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, hitting, jumping, or punching a cloud does not make rain fall out. Air planes go thru clouds all the time without rain happening. It's a visual gag, a joke in a cartoon movie for the sake of a joke.

Comment: Ok. But then, what's the joke? Because I don't get it

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro it's a sight gag. It looks funny. That's it.